# React Router: Exclude strings from generic `/:slug` path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm attempting to setup the following UI based on routes

- `/things/` - display the list of items (Component A)
- `/things/new` - display the list of items, with a modal form overlay (Component A and Component B)
- `/things/:slug` - display a specific item (Component C)

With this setup:

- `/things/` would display Component A
- `/things/new` would display Component A AND Component B
- `/things/:slug` would display ONLY Component C

This is all in a nested route - `/things`. Which means the `path` from `useRouteMatch` returns `/things`

I have tried several combos with `Switch`, and attempted to use `matchPath` and `useRouteMatch` to differentiate `/new` from `/:slug` but with no luck. Every attempt results in one of the paths not returning the correct component.

For example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:slug(exclude "new")" exact component={ComponentC} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={ComponentA} />
</Switch>
<Route path="/new" component={ComponentB} />
```

Another option I've tried with no luck is to use regex on the slug, to match the slug pattern. Let's says the slug pattern is `xxx-xxx-xxx-###`, then I tried:

```
<Route path="/:slug((\w*-)*(\d*))" component={ComponentC) />
```

but this doesn't match the routes for some reason.

I'm thinking I could use `location.pathname` but this seems like a hack.

Is it possible to match and render routes as described above with standard `<Route path="[something]" />` components with this setup?

Comment: can't we use `exact` for the path `/things/new`?

Comment: We can, but then the problem becomes how to display Component A on `/things/new` but not on `/things/:slug(not new)` - and `/things/:slug` will still match `/new`

Answer (score 1):

This is why I love Stack Overflow. Asking the question often leads you to answer it yourself.

I was browsing the React Router docs for info on the regex and discovered the `Route` `path` property can accept an array of paths. So I went with this:

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch()

<Route path={[path, `${path}/new`]} exact component={ThingsList} />
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/new`} render={() => <NewThing path={path} />} />
  <Route path={`${path}/:slug`} render={() => <Thing path={path} />} />
</Switch>
```